# Flutter web website takes a long time to load initially

Tags: flutter, web, flutter-web

I am currently creating a flutter web application for a client, however, when the website is navigated to for the first time in the browser, the page loads to a blank screen and a few seconds later shows the actual homepage widgets. After the page has been cached in it seems to be quicker on subsequent reloads.

Is there something that I can change about my flutter web app in order to decrease this initial load time? I know that flutter web is still in beta, so it may just be that -- will this be fixed when flutter web becomes deployment ready?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you doing this in production mode or debug?

Comment: I am also facing same issue. You got any solution ?

Comment: My solution was to create the site using the Django framework instead. Easy enough to learn using bootstrap CSS and quick to make the site. More information readily available online to help aswell

Comment: The web is in stable but the problem is always the same

Comment: You can use this command `flutter run -d chrome --dart-define=FLUTTER_WEB_USE_SKIA=true`, The `--dart-define=FLUTTER_WEB_USE_SKIA=true` parameter will set the constant to use Skia. Read about [web renderers](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/web-renderers)

Comment: Here is a solution to the problem for now. [You can take a look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71456514/14208424)

Comment: Because of this https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/97228

Answer (score 12):

Before running certain views, especially the first time the web app is built, it takes a moment to load everything up. The best thing to do in such case is to add a loading screen/widget.

You should have a look at [this article](https://itnext.io/fix-flutter-web-loading-time-with-a-loading-spinner-c5dd36a29f5b) by Juan Curti.

Answer (score 4):

I think a found a solution for that, let me know if it works!

I posted it [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/76009#issuecomment-1042073205)... Basically you need to add two lines to the `<head>...</head>` tag on your index file to start loading the CanvasKit binary from the beginning.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/canvaskit-wasm@0.33.0/bin/canvaskit.js"></script>
<link rel="preload" href="https://unpkg.com/canvaskit-wasm@0.33.0/bin/canvaskit.wasm" as="fetch" crossOrigin="anonymous">
```

Be careful with which URL you use above, there is a better explanation on the link above! Hope it helps at least a bit with your initial loading time!

Answer (score 4):

Consider using ditman's solution in

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/76009#issuecomment-1095663169

He puts an example of his solution at

https://dit-tests.web.app

Comment: Sadly, this page still takes a _long_ time to load, see: https://pagespeed.web.dev/report?url=https%3A%2F%2Fdit-tests.web.app 32 on "performance" score.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this flutter example to resolve the bootstrap white screen initial load.

[Flutter Gallery web example](https://github.com/flutter/gallery/blob/master_archived/web/index.html)

The instance of the white screen will display the app icon loading animation once the flutter app bootstrapped the loader icon will hide and the flutter app show.

```
<div id="loading">
<style>
  body {
    inset: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: fixed;
  }

  #loading {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
  }

  #loading img {
    animation: 1s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate breathe;
    opacity: .66;
    transition: opacity .4s;
  }

  #loading.main_done img {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  #loading.init_done img {
    animation: .33s ease-in-out 0s 1 forwards zooooom;
    opacity: .05;
  }

  @keyframes breathe {
    from {
      transform: scale(1)
    }

    to {
      transform: scale(0.95)
    }
  }

  @keyframes zooooom {
    from {
      transform: scale(1)
    }

    to {
      transform: scale(10)
    }
  }
</style>
<img src="icons/Icon-192.png" alt="Loading indicator..." /></div>
<script>
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  var loading = document.querySelector('#loading');
  _flutter.loader.loadEntrypoint({
    serviceWorker: {
      serviceWorkerVersion: serviceWorkerVersion,
    }
  }).then(function (engineInitializer) {
    loading.classList.add('main_done');
    return engineInitializer.initializeEngine();
  }).then(function (appRunner) {
    loading.classList.add('init_done');
    return appRunner.runApp();
  }).then(function (app) {
    // Wait a few milliseconds so users can see the "zoooom" animation
    // before getting rid of the "loading" div.
    window.setTimeout(function () {
      loading.remove();
    }, 200);
  });
});
```